# What were Garrett and Coulson drawing?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In the season finale of [Agents Of S.H.I.E.L.D](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3609170/?ref_=tt_ep_ep22) we saw Garrett was drawing something like a universe or multiverse like thing. Later Coulson saw that and inspired to draw again in wall. So what was that?

Comment: Based on the electrical engineering design, it's the schematic for Ultron.

Comment: It might be some kind of Kree code. http://www.dailydot.com/geek/agents-of-shield-season-finale/

Answer (score 6):

It was revealed in [*The Writing On The Wall* (S02E07)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Writing_on_the_Wall) that Garret, Coulson and a number of other former agents were drawing segments of a map.

The segments fit together in a three dimensional space, which no one had noticed until now.

[image: the map is 3d!]

[image: put it all together]

Once put together, it appeared to be a map of a lost city or large temple of some sort.

[image: it's a city!]

During the events of [*The Things We Bury* (S02E08)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Things_We_Bury), the team learns that the lost city is located below San Juan, Puerto Rico.

The assumption by most fans is that the lost city is actually [Attilan](http://marvel.com/universe/Attilan), which figures heavily into the backstory of the Inhumans, but there has been no confirmation of this fact as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: we don't know.  Yet.  This is likely to be part of Coulson's Season 2 story arc.

I think Garrett drew it first because he had more samples of GH-325 put into him than Coulson did.  I beleive once Coulson saw Garrett's drawing, it triggered it in his mind.  I personally think this is what drives people mad (as Coulson alluded to in his report to Fury).

Some of the comments over on [io9's review](http://io9.com/can-the-agents-of-shield-stand-for-protecting-people-ev-1576504064/all) of the season finale recall that this formula was seen before in the episode "Eye Spy."